# Xcode external build tool target with dependencies on built executables

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I am writing a swift CLI app, and am doing acceptance testing on it using [Bats (Bash Automated Testing System)](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core). I have an "external build tool" target that invokes bats from a shell script. This target declares dependencies on a few CLI app executable targets (including my main app). Then I have a scheme that builds the Bats target and also runs an XCTest target.

I haven't been able to consistently guarantee that the executable dependencies finish building completely before the Bats script is invoked. Whether I declare my scheme as parallelizable or not, I will inconsistently run into issues where the Bats script is invoked, but it can't find one of the executables it depends on since it hasn't yet been added to $TARGET_BUILD_DIR.

From the build logs, I can always see that the needed executable target has finished compiling, but when the issue occurs, the target is conspicuously missing completed steps for `Link <executable>`, `Sign <executable>`, and `Register execution policy exception for <executable>`.

My best interpretation of the problem is that Xcode releases locks for the target with the dependencies only once all dependencies have finished compiling, and not necessarily when the builds for those targets have completed fully.

The most reliable workaround I have found is to `sleep 1` in my shell script before invoking Bats. I also tried putting an aggregate target in between my external build tool target and the dependencies, but this didn't work reliably. **Is there a way to have Xcode delay execution of the external build tool until the build of the dependent targets has fully completed?**

Comment: hi. I have same problem now. I have  2 targets A & B. A is dependent on B. When I build A, it builds B first and copies (thru a Run Script) the framework output of B to a specific folder. This folder path is used  by A to  search for header files.  I kinda suspect that Xcode builds target A way to early when the Run Script is not yet done. Im looking for ways to delay it or make it totally synchronous. Have u found a better way?